# Could not create service of type DependenciesAccessorsWorkspaceProvider

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My local storage in Mac already full then i move my new workspace to external storage. I tried to checkout a project and build it with new location path (in this case in /Volumes/SDMICRO/ANDROID/kotlin-coroutines-master/advanced-coroutines-codelab). But after i build this error appears.

```
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type DependenciesAccessorsWorkspaceProvider using DependencyManagementBuildSessionScopeServices.createDependenciesAccessorsWorkspace().
   > Timeout waiting to lock dependencies-accessors (/Volumes/SDMICRO/ANDROID/kotlin-coroutines-master/advanced-coroutines-codelab/.gradle/7.0.2/dependencies-accessors). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: unknown
     Our PID: 1857
     Owner Operation: unknown
     Our operation: 
     Lock file: /Volumes/SDMICRO/ANDROID/kotlin-coroutines-master/advanced-coroutines-codelab/.gradle/7.0.2/dependencies-accessors/dependencies-accessors.lock
```

and the build gradle file looks so weird
[image: img]

Please help me, How to run my project with different location of storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to the menu
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart, then in the dialog click on "Invalidate and Restart"
Solved for me

Comment: I have found the answer almost same, there some additional things to do. Delete all ._gradle and try invalidate and restart and now my project can run. Thanks